# Dynamic src path with CSS animation

Tags: javascript, angularjs, dom, css-animations, getelementbyid

I tried to make an img with a dynamic path. The common solution seemed to use

```
 document.getElementById();
```

I did that but I got a problem : my controller was called before the html was loaded and I get an error because the id was referring to nothing. I understood the problem and the solutions seemed to be

1) Put the script in a

```
 <script>
```

balise under the page. This should work, but I want to call getElementById() in my controller, as the path I want to do depends on parameters (it's actually the controller of a uibmodal). 
Consequently, as I can't pass the parameters from the controller to the script balise in my HTML, it's no longer a solution.

2) I also tried to use window.onload(), but when I try that, the onload function is not called at all.
Furthermore, I remember had trying this and even when the function was called, it was too late because the img need to be used in an animation.

I kinda run out of steam and really don't see what to do. I'm working with angular thus I didn't try solution based on JQuery, but I thought there was no reason they were more relevant that window.onload.

Does anyone know how to solve that issue ?

```js
(function() {
    'use strict';

    angular
        .module('objectifDtyApp')
        .controller('MyBadgeController',MyBadgeController);

            MyBadgeController.$inject = ['$uibModalInstance', '$state', '$stateParams', 'BadgeView', 'items', 'Lesson'];

            function MyBadgeController($uibModalInstance, $state, $stateParams, BadgeView, items, Lesson) {
            var vm = this;


            console.log(items);

            vm.blocName = items.title;
            vm.ImagePath = items.path;
            console.log(vm.ImagePath);

            window.onload = function(){
                console.log("called");
                var img =document.getElementById('ImgBadge');
                img1.src= vm.ImagePath;

            };


            function clear () {
                $uibModalInstance.dismiss('cancel');
            }

             vm.close = function() {

             $uibModalInstance.close(true);
             //$state.go('viewCourse', {id: $stateParams.idLesson});
             }
         }
    })();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div>
<div class="Badge_logo-demo">
    <img ng-click="vm.close()" src="" alt="Badge_logo" id= "ImgBadge" class="Badge_logo">
    <h2 class="Badge_byline" id="Badge_byline"> You successfully did the Block {{vm.blocName}} </h2>

</div>
</div>
```

Here is a snippet, it obviously doesn't work but it is to show my code. I didn't put CSS as it is not relevant. 
But if there is a solution, it can be checked with that snippet by putting the absolute path of the image in vm.ImgPath.

I precise that everything is called at the opening of the uibmodal, so it's not about forgetting ng-controller or whatever. The {{blocName}} is working for me aswell.

Comment: In a nutshell, what are you trying to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use angular scope to dynamically change the src of your js files, images or css.

This is an example from my own application for css:

```
<link data-ng-if="brand" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" data-ng-href="css/app/brand/{{brand.type}}/brand.css" />
```

where in the controller above we have a property:

```
$scope.brand = {type:"cocacola"}
```

we then allow the user to manipulate that scope variable using a dropdown to set it with ng-model="brand.type"

notice the `data-ng-if="brand"` we check if the controller has loaded the property yet. The advantage is that you don't need to use basic javascript but you can do it the angular way

Comment: Worked very well.

So stupid from me not even looking at ng-src or data-ng-href and trying to find risky and buggy solutions. Angular is always the simpliest.

Thanks for the fast and very clear answer !